# Find the gradient of the curve $y² - 3xy = x²$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Given a curve $y² - 3xy = x²$, express $y$ in terms of $x$.
Find the gradient of the curve when $x=4$.

My attempt,

$y^2-3xy-x^2=0$

$y=\frac{3x \pm \sqrt{13x^2}}{2}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}(3 \pm \frac{\sqrt{13}x}{\sqrt{x^2}})$

When $x=4$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{13}}{2}$

Am I correct?

Comment: **NOTE**: Your answer is correct but you can simplify your expression for $y$ by using the fact that $\sqrt{13x^2}=x\sqrt{13}$

Comment: Is it possible to find gradient at abscissa only, without specifying the ordinate?

Comment: @piepi - This equation represents a pair of intersecting lines - so the gradients of these lines are in fact independent of $x$ and $y$

Answer (score 1):

Your work is correct.

If I may suggest (this would be still more impressive for more complex functions :e.g. $y^6-3xy=x^2$): the implicit function theorem is very useful for this kind of problems.

Consider the function $$F=y^2 - 3xy - x^2=0$$ Taking derivatives $$F'_x=-3y-2x$$  $$F'_y=2y-3x$$ and now $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=\frac{3y+2x}{2y-3x}$$ what you can apply anywhere; you are just facing the problem of solving the quadratic in $y$ for a given value of $x$ afterwards.

Comment: This dy/dx requires x and y both to be mentioned. In the question only x is provided as 4.

Comment: @piepi. You are correct but the advantage of using the implicit function theorem is that you have the analytical derivative everywhere. Now, knowing the value of $x$ requires to compute afterwards the value of $y$ which can be non-analytic and then which will need to be computed by a numerical method. Tell me if this is clear for you since it is very important (for you and me !!).

Comment: Let me dumb down a little(I am still a novice). The implicit function theorem yields the same result  as if you are using the chain rule(I have tried). Second, how is a derivative related to being analytic or not? I only consider limits. if they exist and are valid then it is more than enough for me.

Comment: @piepi. I think that I did not explain properly. The advantage of the implicit function theorem is that, whatever the function could be, you get an **analytical** expression of the derivative in terms of $x,y$. Now, the problem is the value of $y$ for a given $x$; there could be several (as here) and may be they will need to be computed numerically; suppose $F=y^6-3xy-x^2$; $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3y+2 xy}{6 y^5-3 x}$. Now, for $x=4$, you need to solve $y^6-12 y-16=0$ for $y$. No analytical solution and two real roots ($y_1\approx -1.145$, $y_2\approx 1.834$). Now, I can compute$\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: Wow. Now I see. Thanks.

Comment: @piepi. Good to know ! The function can be as bizarre as you wish. The problem will stay the same. In my last example, beside the two real roots, there also four complex solutions and I can compute the derivatives which will be complex numbers !!